# How to avoid objects copying during passing from C++ to QML and again to C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I try to load QImage from C++ to QML. So I already created subclass of QQuickPaintedItem in which I load my QImage(casted to QVariant) using slot(that means that I use QML in this case only as transfer). But I have only one issue: I pass the QImage by value, and I know that I can't pass arguments from QML to C++ using references and pointers.

**So, whether there is a some trick which allows to avoid objects copying during passing from C++ to QML and again to C++?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "trick" is built in to Qt: Like many other classes which contain data, `QImage` uses implicit data sharing AKA copy-on-write/CoW, [quote from Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#details):

> QImage objects can be passed around by value since the QImage class uses [implicit data sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html).

Link in the docs provides more details about what this means in context of Qt, but in short actual `QImage` instance is very small and cheap to pass around as value. It is basically just a pointer to shared data with reference count. When an instance is modified, it is *detached* (deep copy taken) first if reference count is greater than 1, but when not modifying, it's just copying around a pointer.